# Angular GET request to download a file with Auth header

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have a Spring controller that serves a file at the url localhost:8080/files/1/file.avi

The get request requires a valid Authorization token in the request header.

In my angular app I would like to call this api with the Auth header and start the download of the file. How can I do that?

I have seen answers that point to just redirecting to the url but I cannot do that as I need to pass the header to the call.